# D3 Crossfilter grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm banging my head against a problem on D3 Crossfilter:

I've got an array of "trips":

```
var trips = crossfilter(
   { id:0, somedatainfo:"foo1", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:0, area_name:"Duomo"},
   { id:1, somedatainfo:"foo2", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:1, area_name:"Navigli"},
   { id:2, somedatainfo:"foo3", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:0, area_name:"Ticinese"},
   { id:3, somedatainfo:"foo4", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:0, area_name:"Ticinese"},
   { id:4, somedatainfo:"foo5", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:1, area_name:"Navigli"},
   { id:5, somedatainfo:"foo6", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:1, area_name:"Duomo"},
   { id:6, somedatainfo:"foo7", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:1, area_name:"campo di marte"},
   { id:7, somedatainfo:"foo8", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:0, area_name:"rifredi"}
   { id:8, somedatainfo:"foo9", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:0, area_name:"rifredi"}
   { id:9, somedatainfo:"foo10", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:1, area_name:"campo di marte"}
);
```

I want to get two records (for two charts) of the two city, grouped by the area id:

```
groupMilan = 
[
     { id:0, somedatainfo:"foo1", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:0, area_name:"Duomo"},
     { id:1, somedatainfo:"foo2", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:1, area_name:"Navigli"},
     { id:2, somedatainfo:"foo3", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:0, area_name:"Ticinese"},
     { id:3, somedatainfo:"foo4", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:0, area_name:"Ticinese"},
     { id:4, somedatainfo:"foo5", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:1, area_name:"Navigli"},
     { id:5, somedatainfo:"foo6", city_id:0, city_name:"milan" , area_id:1, area_name:"Duomo"}
];

groupFlorence = 
[
     { id:6, somedatainfo:"foo7", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:1, area_name:"campo di marte"},
     { id:7, somedatainfo:"foo8", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:0, area_name:"rifredi"}
     { id:8, somedatainfo:"foo9", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:0, area_name:"rifredi"}
     { id:9, somedatainfo:"foo10", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:1, area_name:"campo di marte"}
];
```

I did this with:

```
var city = trips.dimension(function(d){return d.city_id;});
```

So I tried to group the value and print to console:

```
var groupByArea = city.group();
console.log("GROUP:");
groupByArea.top(Infinity).forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log(p.key + ": " + p.value);
});
console.log("END GROUP");
```

So what I've got is exacly

```
"GROUP:"
"1: 8959" // The real number of records of milan city
"2: 1060" // The real number of records of florence city
"END GROUP"
```

Now I filter the record getting only florence ones:

```
city.filter(2);
```

All ok, but now I need to pass to the chart the records of city grouped by the area_id...
So if I press on the Florence City chart and select to filter for example the **area_id=1**, the total records of the page should be just:

```
 [
    { id:6, somedatainfo:"foo7", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:1, area_name:"campo di marte"},
    { id:9, somedatainfo:"foo10", city_id:1, city_name:"florence" , area_id:1, area_name:"campo di marte"}
 ];
```

// just for info, The Chart is a "dc.geoChoroplethChart" and show the city areas :

```
 var florencecity   : dc.geoChoroplethChart("#area-florence-chart");
 charts.florencecity
                .width(width)
                .height(height)
                .dimension(city)
                .group(groupByArea)
                //.colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
                //.colorDomain([0, 200])
                //.colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? florencecity.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
                .overlayGeoJson(areasjson.features, "quartiere", function (d) {
                    //console.log(d.properties);
                    return d.properties.to_char;
                })
                .title(function (d) {
                    return "State:" + d.key + "\nTotal Amount Raised: " + d.value + "M";
                })
                .projection(
                        d3.geo.stereographic()
                        .center([11.1497741, 43.780539])//[3.9,43.0])
                        .scale(300000)
                        .translate([width / 4 , height / 2])

                )
                ;
```

Preview: [image]

**UPDATE:**

As required, I made a jsFiddle Version:
http://jsfiddle.net/305enqg5/!

Answer (score 2):

You groupByArea actually groups by city, doesn't it? So you Florence cloropleth in the example is actually colored based on city totals, not area totals. You would probably want to:

```
var area = trips.dimension(function(d){return d.area_id;});
var groupByArea = area.group();
var florencecity = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#area-florence-chart");
florencecity
                .width(width)
                .height(height)
                .dimension(area)
                .group(groupByArea)
                .overlayGeoJson(areasjson.features, "quartiere", function (d) {
                    return d.properties.to_char;
                })
                .projection(
                        d3.geo.stereographic()
                        .center([11.1497741, 43.780539])//[3.9,43.0])
                        .scale(300000)
                        .translate([width / 4 , height / 2])

                );
```

Then either filter you data down to just Florence by creating your city dimension and filtering on it, or (if you want to display more than one city at a time) use a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to remove all non-Florence data from the group you use in the Florence chart.

Comment: var filtered_group = remove_milan_area(areas) 

    function remove_milan_area(source_group) { return {
        all:function () {
           return source_group.all().filter(
               function(d) {
                   /* How i get d.fleet_id ?
                     d = { key: fleet_id , value : int? } */
     return d;
               });
           }
        };
     }

Comment: The formatting here is terrible, unfortunately, so it's tough to read. But what do you need fleet_id for?

Comment: As you sad, to remove from the fakegroup the milan records!

Comment: Your answer is correct! If I set my chorophlet with dimension = area and group = groupByArea, when I press a value like 1 (that is the id_area present in both the citys) the crossfilter get 0 record beacause it faults.

Comment: So I need a fakegroup where I dropout the area_id of the milan city. But the filter function of fakegroupping it returns only the value set in the dimentions function (in this case the id_area, and not the ohters (like the fleet_id, that I need to know of witch city the value is associated)

Comment: I don't think that should be happening. Can you put together an example on jsFiddle or something similar? To filter out particular cities using a fake group you'll have to construct your group/dimension a bit differently. It's a lot easier to explain by changing an example, so if you could build one it would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/305enqg5/1/  There is something wrong with your geojson - many of the areas have the same id property, which I suspect isn't correct.